# Using 'R' and "aws.s3" how to push a directory to the cloud

Tags: r, amazon-s3, subdirectory

I have a directory with subdirectories and many files that need to be pushed to Amazon S3.  I am using the 'R' tool.

Is there a clean/easy way to say "push this directory and everything in it up to S3"?  I am hoping to avoid pushing things up one at a time, and manually re-building the directory structures.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass file names to `put_object()` using their full path names and then use those path names as their object keys, then you can implicitly recreate a directory structure. Basically like this (though you may want to change the filenames when using them as object keys in some way):

```
library("aws.s3")
lapply(dir(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE), function(filename) {
    put_object(file = filename, object = filename, bucket = "mybucket")
})
```

There is also an experimental function `s3sync()` that should do this for a complete file tree (but it isn't widely tested):

```
s3sync()
```

Comment: Hi, Thomas! I checked your code. It works. But 2 things should be solved: 1) specify directory name in "dir(<directory_name>, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)"; 2) after re-creating local directory structure an additional directory with "_____" appears. The files were in this directory. Is it right or can I need to do something. Thanks !

Comment: @andrii This code assumes you want the current directory (so first arg to `dir()` is empty); but you can specify a different directory if you're trying to copy other files. Not sure where the `___` comes from - that's kind of weird.